# Swift / Objective C - performTransitionOperation Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I've been going at this for a while now and I'd love to hear some potential solutions. Essentially, I'm trying to incorporate a right menu/nav using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), but when I attempt to go log into the app and go to my home screen/logged in landing, the app crashes. The app doesn't crash when the segue is a modal,etc. but it continues to crash while it's set to the appropriate segue for the plugin I'm currently using.

Here is the console output when the app crashes:

> 2016-11-12 22:21:04.861 Freely Market[16811:3049283] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Freely_Market.LoginViewController _performTransitionOperation:withViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc71950ea30'

For those who will wonder what the UI of the application looks like - here:

[image: User Interface Image]

1 is the login button, that is where the user is then passed onto the following screen pending that their information matche what is stored within the system.

2 is the segue, sw_front

3 is the logged in screen

4 is the segue sw_right

5 is the menu

The segues are set up properly, and I think I'm onto the right track when it comes to finding out exactly what the issue is here..

Here is where the error is at, or where it is decoding from: \

```
- (void)perform
{
    SWRevealControllerOperation operation = SWRevealControllerOperationNone;

    NSString *identifier = self.identifier;
    SWRevealViewController *rvc = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dvc = self.destinationViewController;

    if ( [identifier isEqualToString:SWSegueFrontIdentifier] )
        operation = SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceFrontController;

    else if ( [identifier isEqualToString:SWSegueRearIdentifier] )
        operation = SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRearController;

    else if ( [identifier isEqualToString:SWSegueRightIdentifier] )
        operation = SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRightController;

    if ( operation != SWRevealControllerOperationNone )
        [rvc _performTransitionOperation:operation withViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

So from what I can tell, the application thinks that it is using this selector: `_performtransitionOperation:withViewController:animated:]`

But that is obviously not Swift, and is Objective-C. So I'm not quite sure how to get my segue to actually operate as it should.

This is where the segue is being called from after verifying the user's login information.

```
} else if (username.isEqual(to: usernameV!) && password.isEqual(to: passwordV!)) {

       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sw_front", sender: self)
```

And this is where I am stuck, maybe it is just an issue with Objective-C and Swift clashing? Other's have gotten this add-in to work just fine without any issues, but I have not. Maybe it is because I am verifying user login information and then passing it onto this new screen, where as others just start at the basic screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved.

I needed to create a separate view controller in between the login confirmation and the instances where SWRevealViewController would be called.

If you would like to read into the issue further on the Git repository for SWRevealViewController, you can do so here: [SWRevealViewController Issue #642](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/642)

An image view of what I am speaking about can be found here:

[image]